# How to check if post request was succesfull or no in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I have Action in Redux.
Where I make request to backEnd to do something.
And I need to check if Post request whichIi made was successful or no.

```
export const changeEmployee = (id, status) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch(changeEmployeeRequest());
        await adminAPI.changeEmployee(id, status);
        dispatch(updateUserWithRolesSuccess(usersWithRoles))
      } catch (error) {
      dispatch(updateUserWithRolesFailure());
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I do not receive any data from this request. So I cannot check it works.
But I was curious is there are any ways to get status of request.
As I can see this status in Chrome's Network tab.

And this is my API, which is in separate APIs page.

```
export const changeEmployee = (id, status) => API.post(`${UPDATE_EMPLOYEE}`, {id, status});
```

Comment: Where do you actually send the request? Share code of `adminAPI.changeEmployee`

Comment: @Han Moe Htet
I updated question

Comment: Ok, seems that you are using axios. Axios throws error if the response status is 4xx or 5xx. So what you have done in your 1st snippet is correct. You can handle the error (request failure) in the catch block.

Comment: @HanMoeHtet Unfortunately i can't catch it, try doesn't pick up.
So requests  is treated as succesfu although it’s not.

Comment: @KarinaShulan What does `changeEmployee` actually return? You can console.log it or JSON.stringify it and post the result. Most likely, whoever created `API` did include some information about the success of the response.

Comment: @timotgl when i try to do like this :
const res = await adminAPI.addUserRole(newUserRole); 
console.log(res)
I recieve undefined.

Comment: Are you in control of `adminAPI` or is it something external you have to use? Does it have documentation? It's unusual that it doesn't resolve with a value.

Comment: @timotgl Yes i am in control of it.
But i do not recieve any responses from adminApi.
When i try to put function which makes request in AdminApi in to console.
I can see only Promise which is fullfilled

Comment: Then we would need to see the code of `API.post`. It doesn't look like this is a simple wrapper around `axios.post`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to store the response as a value within your function and then check the status of that

```
const res = await adminAPI.changeEmployee(id, status)
if(res.status === 200) {...}
```

As said above, it looks like you are using axios which should throw an error and what will be handled in the catch block. If you have got different outcomes for different errors you can add logic based on the error status code, similar to this:

```
catch (err) {
   switch (err.response.status) {
      case 401:
         ...
         break
      case 400:
         ...
         break
      default:
         ...
         break
  }
}
```

Comment: If OP was using axios, it would throw on a non-2XX status and enter the catch block in the original snippet. Also OP has not confirmed yet that they're indeed using axios.

Comment: I tried to do it like this.
But i recieve undefine always in res.
I surprised that everyone advises me to do it this way.
And it works for everyone except me.